# Linq to XML Not iterating?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file, with a rather large structure. I'm pulling several entities out of it throughout several systems, and its dynamically updated once a day.

I'm using a Linq Query that is exhibiting odd behavior, its only returning if the first entry in the site tag matches the search-pattern. If its number 2 or 3, it fails to return anything. Why would this behave that way?

The following function written in **VB** handles pulling the data

```
Public Function xmlSchoolListBySite() As IEnumerable
   Dim doc As XDocument = loadXML()
   Dim loadedPrograms As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From c In doc.Descendants("Organization") _
                                                         Where c.Descendants("site").Value = MySite.Site.s_Url _ 'contains Result.RawURL.tostring() formatted
                                                         Select c.Element("Title")
        Return loadedPrograms
End Function
```

The following would be a snippet of the **XML structure**

```
<Organization>
   <Title>MegaCorpUSA</Title>
   <CorpCode>SomeCode</CorpCode>
       <programs>
           <program>program1</program>
        </programs>
        <sites>
            <site>site1.com</site>
            <site>site2.com</site>
            <site>localhost</site>
        </sites>
    </Organization>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `Any()` method:

```
where c.Descendants("site").Any(s => s.Value == MySite.Site.s_Url)
```

In VB as Ahmad pointed out:

```
Where c.Descendants("site").Any(Function(s) s.Value = MySite.Site.s_Url)
```

Comment: +1 in VB that would be: `Where c.Descendants("site").Any(Function(s) s.Value = MySite.Site.s_Url)`

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but (Function(s) pertains to what? I'm not finding any implicit examples that shed light on the situation.

Comment: Not sure what it's called in VB, but in C# `s => ...` is a lambda expression.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Looks like it's also called a lambda in VB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163362.aspx